# Which model suits the best for time series forecasting if there is no seasonality in the data but is trending above?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, recurrent-neural-network, forecasting, arima

[This is a image describing trend and seasonality plotted using statsmodel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7X1K.png)Re4Es.png

[This is my data of rice production every year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wu2K.png)

Comment: First image seems to be dead

Comment: Ya now it is edited @IanQuah. Please answer

Answer (score 0):

If there is not seasonality in historical data then you should go for SMA, WMA, Holt Winter, SES. Hope answer to your question.